# The project requires user input

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am working with a VB.net project that was converted from c#.  When I open the project, I see the message:

> The project requires user input.  Reload the project for more information

When I choose Project Reload, I get the message

> The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error

Any idea what this means?

The project builds just fine.  But when I run the project and press the Login button, I get

> File Load Exception Handled

at the line:

```
((ThreadStart)t._start)();
```

In the Output window I see:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException'
>   occurred in TIProData.dll.

In the error dialog it also says:

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'zlib.net,
>   Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=47d7877cb3620160' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Comment: You may need to share some code or supply more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

> Normally this error happens when the version of a referenced assembly
>   differs from what you have in your machine.

Search your machine to see what version of zlib.net file you have in your machine. The project found `zlib.net, Version=1.0.3.0`, but it's not the referenced version and you need to have the same version which is referenced in your machine. Make sure you have the same version of the assembly file available in your machine. This is one solution where you probably might not want to make any other changes to the project.

Another option is to remove the existing reference and add a new reference to zlib.dll, which will be the version you have in your machine. But this might require code change if there is substantial difference or changes are made to the assembly between versions.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a file called zlib.net.dll already on my machine.  I copied that into the project directory and created a reference to it.  Now everything works great.

Answer (score 4):

> The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information

Try running visual studio as an Administrator then open your project

Comment: Please be very careful when running things as administrator, only do this if you know the source and trust the nature of the software

Answer (score 1):

The moving/copying the assembly and updating the reference manually in the project works, but there is a better way.

You should use [NuGet package manager](https://www.nuget.org/) to manage external libraries.  You can even control which version of the library is used with the project.

> About NuGet
>
> When you use NuGet to install a package, it copies the library files
>   to your solution and automatically updates your project (add
>   references, change config files, etc.). If you remove a package, NuGet
>   reverses whatever changes it made so that no clutter is left.

For example, the [zlib library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/zlib/) can be installed and reference in a project with a simple command in [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console).

[image: using the package install command]

Answer (score 0):

The error means you're missing a dependency.

Download and install zlib: http://www.zlib.net/

Then in your VB project, add zlib in the dependencies.

If you still have the problem, you'll have to use Fusion Log Viewer to pinpoint the problem, info is here: [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Comment: Thanks.  I downloaded zlib.net (actually zlib128-dll).  This gave me a zlib1.dll. I copied all the files into the project directory and tried to create a Reference.  When I clicked Browse and pointed to zlib1.dll, I got the message "A reference to "...\zlib1.dll" could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"

Comment: "The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information, The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error" means you're missing zlib? interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I manged to fix this issue by simply running VS in Admin mode. It had to do with permissions for IIS. Only after I moved one of the unopened project to separate folder and tried opening it by itself was I able to to see the IIS issue and the "run as admin" suggestion